# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json

I have following code and I get PHP notices...

```
$tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //JSON decode
$user_name = $tst_msg->name; //fetching name
$msg = $tst_msg->message;// fetching messages
```

I get following notices

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
>  PHP Notice:  Trying to get
>   property of non-object in..

Comment: can you print `$tst_msg` here?

Comment: <pre>stdClass Object
(
    [message] => hi m8
    [name] => m9|m7
)
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

`$tst_mst` is a array and not an object.
For objects you can use the arrow, for arrays you have to adres the key like `$test[key_name]`.

`print_r($tst_msg);` gives you the output, then use `$test_msg['name']` to get the name (if the key in JSON was 'name').

A tutorial is present on the [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) page.

Comment: If I treat it as array I get fatal error. The codes are working but getting notices is irritating.

Comment: Does print_r gives the output or still a fatal error?

Comment: I have no error issues. If I print its gives  
 
<pre>stdClass Object ( [message] => hi m8 [name] => m9|m7 ) </pre>. I given notices which is irritating. Isn't it?

Comment: Your json is not clean, there is a part of a string present before and after the JSON. What is the output of the $recieved_text

Comment: {"message":"hi m9","name":"m7|m9"} is $received_text

Comment: try editing $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text, true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98964/discussion-between-perrykipkerrie-and-tashi).

Comment: but post the solution here

Comment: Result of the chat: I've got no errors in the same script on my server. The poster will try the exact same code I used and will check the outcome